# Flash/AS2 - Two movieclips keep moving position (possibly due to rotation)

Tags: flash, rotation, actionscript-2

I am devising an experiment in which you are asked to distinguish four circles.

The circles are in MovieClips, and there are 8 frames with different circles. After each identification, you move on to the next frame (the next round), until you've done all 8.

The circles are rotated randomly using Actionscript 2.

However, sometimes two circles overlap. This happens randomly, and not always. It might have to do with the rotation. I have no idea why this happens - it shouldn't if you look the the .fla.

Please look at http://dhost.info/lbogaardt/Amplify/ for the .fla and the .swf.

The Circles MovieClip is inside MovieClip Questions.

If you don't see the error, just run it again - it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an issue. It has something to do with naming instances.
I've unified names of the circles. 
You had for example B1 on the right side and in the next frame it was on the left side and flash took the circle from the previous frame.

Working solution here:

http://cloud.kirikirikiri.com/Experiment.fla

Comment: It does seem to work, doesn't it? Thank you so much for the effort. Do you have any idea why it originally did not work? Why would it take a MovieClip from a previous frame? In the current frame, the MovieClips from before should have disappeared, and the new circles (although with the same InstanceName) should be the only ones there... Anyway, problem fixed - thanks!